# How to set different environment variables for different hosts

Tags: environment-variables

We are using NIS and Automount for *nix developing hosts. So I can login any host with the same identity and same home directory.

I hope to set different environment variables when login different hosts. For example, I want to set the LD_LIBRARY_PATH with some value when login the solaris host. However I don't set it when login the linux host.

How should I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use conditionals in your `~/.profile`.

```
case `uname` in
  Solaris)
    PATH=/usr/xpg6/bin:/usr/xpg4/bin:$PATH
    LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$HOME/lib/solaris
    export LD_LIBRARY_PATH;;
esac
```

You might also want to set some aliases and other shell settings differently. These go into your `~/.bashrc` or `~/.zshrc`.

```
case `uname` in
  Solaris)
    alias df='df -k' du='du -k'
    alias ls='ls -F';;
  Linux)
    alias ls='ls --color';;
esac
```

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you use bash as your shell.

Edit your user's ~/.bashrc and add the following line

```
[[ "$(uname)" != "Linux" ]] && export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/solaris_path:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

Comment: `.bashrc` is not the right place to define environment variables as they will only be defined in programs started from a terminal, not programs started from the window manager menu. See e.g. http://superuser.com/questions/183870/difference-between-bashrc-and-bash-profile . `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is an exception though: you may want to define it in `.bashrc` *in addition* to `.profile`, because on some systems (including Ubuntu) some terminals are setuid or setgid in order to write to utmp (quod google), causing them to drop `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`.

Comment: @Gilles, you're right. LD_LIBRARY_PATH is an exception, it need be defined in .bashrc. Then it works on Solaris.